# php jquery and strange characters

Tags: php, jquery, html

Hello o have an html form and a php script and html passes some values with a form in the php script. well here is jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#convert').click(function(){

                //pairno tis times ap tin forma
                var name = $('#name').val();
                var tel = $('#tel').val();
                var tel2 = $('#tel2').val();
                var street = $('#street').val();
                var minconsum = $('#minconsum').val();
                var closedtill = $('#closedtill').val();
                var opentill = $('#opentill').val();
                var city = $('#city').val();
                var type = $('#type').val();

                if($('#city').val()=='ΑΤΤΙΚΗ')
                {
                    var perioxi = $('#perioxiAtt').val();
                }else if($('#city').val()=='ΚΥΠΡΟΣ')
                {
                    var perioxi = $('#perioxiKypr').val();
                }else if($('#city').val()=='ΘΕΣΣΑΛΟΝΙΚΗ')
                {
                    var perioxi = $('#perioxiThess').val();
                }else{
                    var perioxi = $('#perioxiGen').val();
                }   

                var dataString = "name=" + name + "&tel=" + tel + "&tel2=" + tel2 + "&street=" + street  + "&minconsum=" + minconsum + "&closedtill=" + closedtill + "&opentill=" + opentill + "&city=" + city + "&perioxi=" + perioxi + "&type=" + type;


                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax_converter.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(data){
                //pairno ta dedomena
                $('#results').show();

                //vazo ta dedomena sto results div tag.
                $('#results').html(data);
            }
         });
```

and i get the date in my php script as usual

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$tel2 = $_POST['tel2'];
$street = $_POST['street'];
$minconsum = $_POST['minconsum'];
$closedtill = $_POST['closedtill'];
$opentill = $_POST['opentill'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$perioxi = $_POST['perioxi'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
```

everything works fine except the strange charachters &,<,>, etc so that is my problem!

any help would be really helpfull!

here is my html form at least a part of it where i have the problem

```
<label for="name">Όνομα:</label> 
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" />
```

I forgot to mention my output if i enter a name like "zo & za" without the quotes i get "zo" that's all. all the rest of the input string is lost

Comment: You wouldn't expect to be served exactly what you want just by sitting at a table in the library across the street from your favourite restaurant. Please add more detail to your question; what do the characters you list do to your code? What output do you get, and what output do you want?

Comment: Yeah sorry i forgot to mention my output if i enter a name like "zo & za" without the quotes i get "zo" that's all. all the rest of the input string is lost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of readability I would define the Ajax parameters like below and let jQuery convert it into the querystring for you encoding it properly. Building it manually will cause issues if you had an '&' character in one of the variables for example (Christofer Eliasson's answer may do this too):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax_converter.php",
    data: {
        "name": name,
        "tel": tel,
        "tel2": tel2,
        "street": street,
        "minconsum": minconsum,
        "closedtill": closedtill,
        "opentill": opentill,
        "city": city,
        "perioxi": perioxi,
        "type": type
    },
    success: function(data){
        //pairno ta dedomena
        $('#results').show();

        //vazo ta dedomena sto results div tag.
        $('#results').html(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not even sure I understand the question, but my guess is that the problem might be this line:

```
var name = $('#name').html();
```

Since you use `.html()` depending on what type of element `#name` is you might get HTML as your name (your "special characters < > "). If it is an input-element, use `var name = $('#name').val();` instead to get the value.

**Edit**

So I might see what your problem is now, the problem lies in creating your data-string right? That is where you get a problem with special characters?

Instead of doing it your way:

```
var dataString = "name=" + name + "&tel=" + tel + "&tel2=" + tel2 + "&street=" + street  + "&minconsum=" + minconsum + "&closedtill=" + closedtill + "&opentill=" + opentill + "&city=" + city + "&perioxi=" + perioxi + "&type=" + type;
```

You can make use of jQuery's [.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/), and do it this way:

```
var dataString = $("#yourFormId").serialize();
```

This will serialize the entire form for you and create the whole data string - it should take care of your problem with special characters and will make your code a lot easier to read.

Comment: @MpampinosHolmens In that case I think you need to clarify your question a bit, according to JamWaffles comment. What is the problem with your special characters?

Comment: @MpampinosHolmens Still need more input about what the actual problem is? What is the problem with the special characters?

Comment: I forgot to mention my output if i enter a name like "zo & za" without the quotes i get "zo" that's all. all the rest of the input string is lost

Comment: @MpampinosHolmens See my edited answer, I might have understood what your problem is.